# MSSQL LEFT OUTER JOIN easier ways

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have 2 tables in ms-sql 2008

`Data_CardCustomer`
It has >> `CustomerId`,`Code`,`Name`, ... etc fields

`Data_ActionPriceList`
It has >> `CustomerId`,`StockId`,`Price1`,`Price2`,`Price3` fields

I want to aggregate all price whith all customer records.
If `customerId` does not have a price in the `DataActionPriceList` table, it shall return zero.

```
Code,Price1,Price2,Price3
```

Current Query

```
SELECT Code,
Isnull((select Price1 from Data_ActionPriceList where Data_ActionPriceList.CustomerId=Data_CardCustomer.CustomerId and StockId=10005 ),0) As price1,
Isnull((select Price2 from Data_ActionPriceList where Data_ActionPriceList.CustomerId=Data_CardCustomer.CustomerId and StockId=10005 ),0) As price2, 
Isnull((select Price3 from Data_ActionPriceList where Data_ActionPriceList.CustomerId=Data_CardCustomer.CustomerId and StockId=10005 ),0) As price3 
FROM Data_CardCustomer
```

is there easier ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Data_CardCustomer.Code,
    Isnull(Data_ActionPriceList.Price1 ,0) As price1,
    Isnull(Data_ActionPriceList.Price2 ,0) As price2, 
    Isnull(Data_ActionPriceList.Price3 ,0) As price3 
FROM Data_CardCustomer 
left join Data_ActionPriceList on Data_ActionPriceList.CustomerId=Data_CardCustomer.CustomerId and StockId=10005
```

Comment: I was looking, something like that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're right on the way with your idea in your question's title.

```
SELECT
    dcc.Code,
    Isnull(dapl.Price1, 0) As price1,
    Isnull(dapl.Price2, 0) As price2,
    Isnull(dapl.Price3, 0) As price3

FROM
    Data_CardCustomer dcc LEFT JOIN Data_ActionPriceList dapl ON dapl.CustomerId = dcc.CustomerId
```

AND dapl.StockId=10005

Please note: you may also use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`, depending on your expected results. With `JOIN` you'll get only rows with corresponding entries in both of your tables, whereas you'll retrieve all rows from `Data_CardCustomer` using a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: In your query, if a customer don't have any record in Data_ActionPriceList, don't displayed in result. because you use dapl.StockId=10005 On Where not on 'ON'.

Comment: You're right, but depends on what OP expects. It's not completely clear from the question...

Comment: Question clear or not you break the LEFT JOIN by putting the conditions in the where.  There is not purpose to that left.